# Does LLVM/clang have flags to control code padding?

Tags: x86, clang, llvm

I'm working with the LLVM framework (v3.3), clang frontend, X86 target. 
I noticed that I always get little bits of NOPs thrown here and there for good measure, apparently to align parts of the code to 16B (at least loops, perfhaps other blocks too).

For e.g - the nopw at 0x401495 here:

```
  401489:       48 89 44 24 10          mov    %rax,0x10(%rsp)
  40148e:       b9 e8 03 00 00          mov    $0x3e8,%ecx
  401493:       eb 0f                   jmp    4014a4 <main+0x34>
  401495:       66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00    data32 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40149c:       00 00 00 00
  4014a0:       48 8b 40 08             mov    0x8(%rax),%rax
  4014a4:       ff c9                   dec    %ecx
  4014a6:       75 f8                   jne    4014a0 <main+0x30>
  4014a8:       8b 30                   mov    (%rax),%esi
```

I'd imagine that helps branch predictors or the I-cache perform better, but I don't need this optimization right now, and I need to keep this certain part of the code simple and presentable.

Is there a way to disable this code padding through compiler flags? Something like gcc's -fno-align-loops (or similar alignment flags)

I've searched the [manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) and browsed through the LLVM code for anything related to padding, alignment, nops, etc. Nothing relevant pops out.
The only alternative I see is compiling with -Os (which does remove this padding), but that changes the rest of the code too aggressively - I don't want to optimize for space, but rather for readability.

Comment: I find `nop` instructions are useful markers for branch targets in disassembly output, since loops often only have local labels that don't survive compile / disassembly (unlike function entry points).

Answer (score 3):

Old question with no answers, so just a few pointers related to LLVM NOP-padding:

- this [LLVM's RFC](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-November/107223.html) mentions something similar to your example: NOP insertion within loops to improve performance by moving "2 branches out of the same 16B chunk if they both go to the same target". It has been implemented [here](https://reviews.llvm.org/D34393).
- for the actual NOP instructions generation in x86, you can find it in [X86AsmBackend::writeNopData](http://llvm.org/doxygen/X86AsmBackend_8cpp_source.html). This code has been modified several times since its creation; at some point they were some [alternate NOP instructions](https://github.com/Microsoft/llvm/commit/3e00ff9fdcaab9ecdfb36b84ab3ec25286ad2d52#diff-bf698ce3cb834aa6e788c3e286c80239).

I hope that helps a little!